# bash script - grep a json variable

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I would like the simplest solution for my pretty basic bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

    # Weather API url format: http://api.wunderground.com/api/{api_key}/conditions/q/CA/{location}.json
    # http://api.wunderground.com/api/5e8747237f05d669/conditions/q/CA/tbilisi.json

        api_key=5e8747237f05d669
        location=tbilisi
        temp=c

        api=$(wget -qO- http://api.wunderground.com/api/$api_key/conditions/q/CA/$location.json)
        temp_c=$api | grep temp_c
        temp_f=$api | grep temp_f

        if [ $temp = "f" ]; then
            echo $temp_f
        else
            echo $temp_c
        fi
```

`grep` returns empty. This is my first bash script, I'm getting hold of syntax, so please point out obvious errors.

I also don't understand why I have $() for `wget`.

Comment: In your code, `if condition` is always false because nothing modifies `$temp`. It is always `c`

Comment: Hope my edit of the title is appropriate.  I'm not a real hacker, so a list of choppy terms, nouns in a row, sort of gives me a headache.  Apology available on request.

Comment: `bash` is the wrong tool to do `json` parsing.  Perhaps consider [python's](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [ruby's](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) libraries

Comment: or the xml api and xmlstarlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
temp_c=$(echo $api|awk '{print $2}' FS='temp_c":'|awk '{print $1}' FS=',')
temp_f=$(echo $api|awk '{print $2}' FS='temp_f":'|awk '{print $1}' FS=',')
```

Instead of:

```
temp_c=$api | grep temp_c
temp_f=$api | grep temp_f
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting following `JSON` response from curl and storing in variable :

```
CURL_OUTPUT='{ "url": "protocol://xyz.net/9999" , "other_key": "other_value" }'
```

Question :I want to read the url key value and extract the id from that url:

Answer : `_ID=$(echo $CURL_OUTPUT |awk '{print $2}' FS='url":' |awk '{print $1}' FS=',' | awk '{print $2}' FS='"'|awk '{print $4}' FS='/')`